# Deriving from pure virtual template class

Tags: c++, class, templates, virtual, abstract

I belive my problem is simple, yet I cannot manage to overcome it.

I have abstract template class aghContainer and child template class aghVector. I am trying to make aghVector object, but I get an error that I cannot create objects of abstract class. I am pretty sure that I implemented all methods, but maybe I miss something...

#### aghContainer:

```
template <typename T>
class aghContainer {
public:
    virtual ~aghContainer() {}
    virtual void append(T const&) = 0;
    virtual void append(aghContainer<T> const& right) = 0;
    virtual bool replace(const int, T const&) = 0;
    virtual T& at(const int) const = 0;
    virtual int size(void) const = 0;
    virtual bool remove(const int) = 0;
    virtual void clear(void) = 0;
    virtual bool isEmpty(void) = 0;
    virtual int indexOf(T const& _value, int _from = 0) const = 0;
    virtual bool contains(T const& _value, int _from = 0) const = 0;
    virtual void print(ostream&) const = 0;
    virtual bool equal(aghContainer<T> const& right) const = 0;
    virtual bool operator==(aghContainer<T> const& right) const;
    virtual bool operator!=(aghContainer<T> const& right) const;
    virtual T& operator[](const int n) const;
    virtual aghContainer<T>& operator+=(T const& element);
    virtual aghContainer<T>& operator+=(aghContainer<T> const& right);
    virtual aghContainer<T>& operator<<(T const& element);
    virtual aghContainer<T>& operator<<(aghContainer<T> const& right);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, aghContainer<T> const& right);
};
```

#### aghVector:

```
template <typename T>
class aghVector :
    public aghContainer<T> {
public:
    aghVector();
    ~aghVector();
    void append(T const&);
    void append(aghContainer<T> const& right);
    bool insert(const int, T const&);
    bool replace(const int, T const&);
    T& at(const int) const;
    int size(void) const;
    bool remove(const int);
    void clear(void);
    bool isEmpty(void);
    int indexOf(T const& _value, int _from = 0);
    bool contains(T const& _value, int _from = 0) const;
    void print(ostream&) const;
    bool equal(aghContainer<T> const& right) const;

private:
    T* vector;
    unsigned int elements;
    void destroyVector();
};
```

#### Error:

> 'aghVector': cannot instantiate abstract class   Data-Container  G:\CPP\Data-Container\ex3main.cpp   101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of problems I can see on a quick look.

In `aghContainer`

```
 void append(aghContainer<T> const& right) = 0;
```

and in `aghVector`

```
  void append(aghVector<T> const& right);
```

actually overloads the function with a different argument type (since `aghVector` is a distinct type from `aghContainer`.  The inherited `append()` will be hidden and not overridden.

A similar problem for `equal()`.

The declaration of `indexOf()` in `aghContainer` is `const`, and the one in `aghVector` is not.   Therefore, again, the version in `aghVecvtor` hides the inherited function, and does not override it.

Comment: Oh god! You are right! I didn't see I missed const in indexOf(). I shouldn't write code so late at night. But I have a chance to ask, so: how can I force append() in aghVector to take only aghVector, if I must write aghContainer in method header?

Comment: Well .....   I'd step back further from that .... By using inheritance, you are requiring `aghVector::append()` to accept any object of type (derived from) `aghContainer`.  The fact you're now trying to limit that to only work with `aghVector` suggests inheritance is a really bad design decision.

Answer (score 2):

From the `aghContainer` class you have the function

```
void append(aghContainer<T> const& right) = 0;
```

Then in the `aghVector` you have this function:

```
void append(aghVector<T> const& right);
```

The problem is that those are two different functions, which means you don't override the parent class `append` function. leading to `aghVector` still being an abstract class.

Comment: Oh. I was expecting that. Although, changing aghVector in this methods to aghContainer doesn't fix error. And how should I overcome, that I cannot put aghVector in this declaration? I would like this method to work exsclusively with vectors.